# Is transaction isolation level 100% reliable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing some test about the isolation level in SQL Server.
First I create a table called test with this structure:

[image]

Then I run the test code with 2 threads at the same time:

```
use test-db;
go
declare @count int = 0;
while @count<5000
begin
  set transaction isolation level read committed;
  begin transaction;

  declare @max int;
  select @max = coalesce(max(sequence_no),0) from test;
  print @max;
  insert into test (prefix, sequence_no, thread) values ('AAA', @max+1, 1);

  commit transaction;
  set @count = @count+1;
end;
```

The second thread just change the thread number:

```
use test-db;
go
declare @count int = 0;
while @count<5000
begin
  set transaction isolation level read committed;
  begin transaction;

  declare @max int;
  select @max = coalesce(max(sequence_no),0) from test;
  print @max;
  insert into test (prefix, sequence_no, thread) values ('AAA', @max+1, 2);


  commit transaction;
  set @count = @count+1;
end;
```

Under read committed mode, the code should wait for read the max number of sequence when the other thread is not commit, which means they won't generate a same sequence_no.
But it often give me a error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_test'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.test-db'. The duplicate key value is (AAA, 2402).

I test it in repeatable read mode again, and it's the same.

Can someone explain why the reading query between transaction will get crash?
Does it means that isolation level isn't 100% reliable?

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel here and not using an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`? As for the problem, this is a classic race condition.

Comment: This kind of setup requires `SERIALIZABLE`. `READ COMMITTED` is not enough because it doesn't prevent readers from reading the same value, incrementing, then writing -- the code doesn't "look ahead" to see you're going to do an insert "later". The performance impact of serializing the whole thing is considerable, which is exactly why things like identity columns and sequences exist (aside from ease of use, of course).

Comment: I found [this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/) being a good read about this subject

Comment: @Larnu I'm not asking about how to generate a sequence without crash. What my question is why it crash under my transaction setup.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's a race condition (because you aren't locking the row that you are reading so other transactions are free to read the **same** row, as Jeroen mentions), @CarlTin , but still, what you are doing is reinventing the wheel. Functionality to do all of this already exists and they are called the `IDENTITY` property and the `SEQUENCE` object. This looks and feels like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). Neither of these features will suffer the problem you have.

Comment: @JeroenMostert But when I being a transaction, insert something and not commit it, then open another query to do something like select *, It did wait until I commit the transaction in first thread. Why it doesn't wait on the upon example?

Comment: @CarlTin it'll wait for the `INSERT` but, again, you have **nothing** to stop 2 separate transactions from reading the **same** row in your query `select @max = coalesce(max(sequence_no),0) from test;` As such, those 2 transactions will attempt to `INSERT` the **same** value for `sequence_no` and you get an error.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think `UPDLOCK` should suffice under `READ COMMITTED`? The only difference would be if the set of rows being read is empty, then `READ COMMITTED` would not lock the non-existence of rows.

Comment: @Charlieface: yes, but when you include explicit locking hints and you're consistent about it (which is certainly not a bad idea, but beyond the knowledge level of the question) the (outer) transaction isolation level is effectively no longer relevant, only that you actually begin a transaction. My remark is strictly about how to do it if you only set the isolation level for a whole transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SERIALIZABLE isolation and an UPDLOCK is also required to avoid deadlocks:

```
SELECT @max = coalesce(max(sequence_no),0)
FROM dbo.test WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE);
```

This is awful for concurrency so you should really use an identity or a sequence.